# Rscript - knitr: substr function not working correctly inside knitr code chunk

Tags: r, knitr, rscript

The following code does not work correctly inside knitr code chunk (it does not extract the desired substring):

What might be causing this behavior?

```
#Retrieve the earliest date
 earlydate <- min(time(month[1]), "2016-04-20")

 earlydate

 #Extract YYYY-MM from earliest date
 substr(earlydate, 1, 7)
```

where month[1] is

```
            TSLA.Open TSLA.High TSLA.Low TSLA.Close TSLA.Volume TSLA.Adjusted
  2016-02-16     158.7    162.95   154.11     155.17     5556300   155.17

#extracts the date:
time( month[1] ) 

   2016-02-16
```

Expect to see the following in knitr output (R Markdown):

```
## [1] 2016-02
```

Instead actual output is not extracted, just show original text:

```
## [1] 2016-02-16
```

However either of the following does works correctly (extracts YYYY-MM):

```
#inline r code
`r substr("2016-02-16", 1,7)`
```

**outputs:** ## [1] 2016-04

````
#knitr code chunk
```{r test, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

earlydate <- "2016-02-16"

earlydate

 #Extract YYYY-MM from earliest date
 substr(earlydate, 1, 7)

```
````

**outputs:** ## [1] 2016-04

**Class Details**
   When both are arguments are type **Date**

```
#Retrieve the earliest date
 earlydate <- min(time(month[1]), as.Date("2016-04-20"))

 class(earlydate)
 ## [1] "Date"
```

When one is type date and the other type "character"

```
#Retrieve the earliest date
 earlydate <- min(time(month[1]), "2016-04-20")

 class(earlydate)
 ## [1] "Date"
```

**Additional Info**

***Environment***

```
OS: Win7

RStudio Version 0.99.892

Rx64 3.2.4 (R version)

document type: shiny knitr doc (.Rmd)

Library: quantmod

Library: knitr
```

The substr function does not appear to extract the substring in a shiny knitr Rmd document.

Details are in the following stackflow link:

[Rscript - knitr: substr function not working correctly inside knitr code chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904010/rscript-knitr-substr-function-not-working-correctly-inside-knitr-code-chunk)

**Minimal Reproducible Example** (this does not extract desired substring):

```
substr( min( as.Date(2013-03-14), "2016-04-20"), 1,7)
outputs: ## [1] "2013-03-14"
```

**Expect** (this works as expected):

```
substr( min( as.Date(2013-03-14), as.Date("2016-04-20")), 1,7)
　outputs (desired): ## [1] "2013-03"
```

It appears unrelated to knitr, since this behavior is also seen on the R console. Returned classes (as stated above) and data processing do not appear to correlate. It would appear to be an underlying ***R issue***.

**Is this WAD?**

BR/KK

Comment: I am aware that classes are not the same,

 class(month[1]) is **"Date"**


class("2016-04-20") is **"character"**

however,


class(earlydate)  is **"Date"**

But using **as.Date** on the character object **resolves the problem** observed.
 

   ** earlydate <- min(time(month[1]), as.Date("2016-04-20"))**

Yields result:

   ** ## [1] "2016-02"**

What could explain this behavior?

Comment: Please provide the data for `earlydate` via: `dput(earlydate)`

Comment: dput(earlydate)
structure("16847", class = "Date")  no difference for earlydate via dput if generated with mixed types (date, character) and or same type (Date, Date) in **min** function. The same value is returned by dput in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

First, to show what a *minimal self-contained reproducible* example means, this is all you need to demonstrate the problem:

```
x1 = as.Date('2013-03-14')
x2 = min(x1, '2016-04-20')
substr(x1, 1, 7)  # "2013-03"
substr(x2, 1, 7)  # "2013-03-14"
```

To investigate the issue, take a look at what these objects really are:

```
dput(x1, '')  # structure(15778, class = "Date")
dput(x2, '')  # structure("15778", class = "Date")
```

`x2` is essentially a character string `"15778"` masked by a class `Date`. What does that mean? I do not know (dates are often represented as integers internally instead of characters). It is just a weird object returned by `min()`, when you asked for the minimum of a date and a character string (I do not know what that means, but R returns something anyway).

Why can this object be problematic? Take a look at the source code of `substr()`:

```
> substr
function (x, start, stop) 
{
    if (!is.character(x)) 
        x <- as.character(x)
    .Internal(substr(x, as.integer(start), as.integer(stop)))
}
```

`is.character(x2)` is `TRUE`, so it is not coerced to character, then it is passed to an internal function (presumably further passed to a certain C function), and I'm not going to dig deeper, since the lesson should be clear now: do not compare apples with oranges. For example, if you want the minimum of two dates, make sure both values are really dates:

```
x2 = min(x1, as.Date('2016-04-20'))
```

Another possibility is to coerce data to a certain type explicitly, e.g. in this case, you want to do `substr()` on a character string, so make sure it is indeed character:

```
substr(as.character(x2), 1, 7)
```

Either way solves your original issue, but the first way is recommended.

Comment: Hi Yihui, thank you for looking into this issue. I was aware on how to workaround this issue, but not certain that underlying code (.internal()) is doing the right thing.  While working through this issue, I came to understand indeed this was not a knitr issue, so my apologies, but an R issue. I would expect some sort warning or error for mixed types.  Thanks again.